# Explanation about the code (print all possible strings of length K)

Tags: java, string, recursion, backtracking

Given a set of characters and a positive integer k, print all possible strings of length k that can be formed from the given set.
Examples:

Input:
`set[] = {'a', 'b'}, k = 3`

Output:

```
aaa
aab
aba
abb
baa
bab
bba
bbb
```

Code:

```
    static void printAllKLengthRec(char[] set,
                               String prefix,
                               int n, int k){

    // Base case: k is 0,
    // print prefix
    if (k == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(prefix);
        return;
    }
 
    // One by one add all characters
    // from set and recursively
    // call for k equals to k-1
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
 
        // Next character of input added
        String newPrefix = prefix + set[i];
         
        // k is decreased, because
        // we have added a new character
        printAllKLengthRec(set, newPrefix,
                                n, k - 1);
    }
}
static void printAllKLength(char[] set, int k)
{
    int n = set.length;
    printAllKLengthRec(set, "", n, k);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("First Test");
    char[] set1 = {'a', 'b'};
    int k = 3;
    printAllKLength(set1, k);
     
    System.out.println("\nSecond Test");
    char[] set2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    k = 1;
    printAllKLength(set2, k);
}
}
```

I don't understand how it got "aab". What I have understood is once it will execute the base case, it will again print "aaa". Can someone please help me understand the flow?

Answer (score 2):

Your code uses recursion inside a for-loop which makes things a bit more complex to understand. A good option in such cases is to add some output logging and visualise the flow (as much as possible) or use a debugger to step through the code.

Below you see an example of such generated output for your code. Now, it becomes much easier to understand what is going on.

The first output `aaa` at **A** is returned after recursively calling the method three times inside the first iteration of the loop. The second iteration inside the inner-most recursive call (**B**) then prefixed `b` (instead of `a` in the first iteration) and calls the method again. There we run into the if-statement because *k=0* and we have the output `aab` at **C**.

Now we go back two layers since the method with *k=0 prefix='aa'* has completed its loop. This means we arrive at the second iteration inside the method with *k=2 prefix='a'* (**D**). There we go down the call stack until *k=0* and we can print the next output.

If you are still unsure how the flow works, I suggest you add some logging and study it further.

```
\ method (k=3, prefix='')
  \ loop (i=0, newPrefix=''+'a')
    \ method (k=2, prefix='a')
      \ loop (i=0, newPrefix='a'+'a')
        \ method (k=1, prefix='aa')
          \ loop (i=0, newPrefix='aa'+'a')
            \ method (k=0, prefix='aaa')        A
            / => output [[aaa]]
          / end-loop
          \ loop (i=1, newPrefix='aa'+'b')      B
            \ method (k=0, prefix='aab')
            / => output [[aab]]                 C
          / end-loop
        / end-method
      / end-loop
      \ loop (i=1, newPrefix='a'+'b')           D
        \ method (k=1, prefix='ab')
          \ loop (i=0, newPrefix='ab'+'a')
            \ method (k=0, prefix='aba')
            / => output [[aba]]
          / end-loop
          \ loop (i=1, newPrefix='ab'+'b')
            \ method (k=0, prefix='abb')
            / => output [[abb]]
          / end-loop
        / end-method
      / end-loop
    / end-method
  / end-loop
  \ loop (i=1, newPrefix=''+'b')
    \ method (k=2, prefix='b')
      \ loop (i=0, newPrefix='b'+'a')
        \ method (k=1, prefix='ba')
          \ loop (i=0, newPrefix='ba'+'a')
            \ method (k=0, prefix='baa')
            / => output [[baa]]
          / end-loop
          \ loop (i=1, newPrefix='ba'+'b')
            \ method (k=0, prefix='bab')
            / => output [[bab]]
          / end-loop
        / end-method
      / end-loop
      \ loop (i=1, newPrefix='b'+'b')
        \ method (k=1, prefix='bb')
          \ loop (i=0, newPrefix='bb'+'a')
            \ method (k=0, prefix='bba')
            / => output [[bba]]
          / end-loop
          \ loop (i=1, newPrefix='bb'+'b')
            \ method (k=0, prefix='bbb')
            / => output [[bbb]]
          / end-loop
        / end-method
      / end-loop
    / end-method
  / end-loop
/ end-method
```

---

Here is the code that produced the output from above:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printAllKLengthRec(new char[]{'a','b'}, "", 3, 0);
}
static void printAllKLengthRec(char[] set, String prefix, int k, int depth) {
    System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat("  ", depth) + "\\ method (k=" + k + ", prefix='" + prefix + "')");
    if (k == 0) {
        System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat("  ", depth) + "/ => output [[" + prefix + "]]");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < set.length; ++i) {
        depth++;
        System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat("  ", depth) + "\\ loop (i=" + i + ", newPrefix='" + prefix + "'+'" + set[i] + "')");
        String newPrefix = prefix + set[i];
        printAllKLengthRec(set, newPrefix, k - 1, depth + 1);
        System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat("  ", depth) + "/ end-loop");
        depth--;
    }
    System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat("  ", depth) + "/ end-method");
}
```